# Talkback is not saying rtl text with Flutter Semantics

Tags: flutter, accessibility, talkback

I am trying to make my app support TalkBack as a lot of the users are blind. I am facing a very weird behaviour where TalkBack is saying some things and completely ignoring others.

Here is the code:

```
Semantics(
    label: "هذا كتاب بعنوان كيف تقرا كتابا",
    excludeSemantics: true,
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: const Text("كيف تقرا كتابا"),
)
```

Here are my observations

1. It reads any English text inside "label" all the time
2. It reads Arabic (rtl language) sometimes depending on what is written. For example, it reads: "هذا الكتاب" but it does not read: "الإعدادات"

Can someone help me with what I should do?

Comment: I'm not sure: but what happens if you'd wrap your widget in a [`Directionality`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html) widget on top of `Semantics`?

Comment: Yes I tried and nothing changed, same thing.